# How to make windows installer package with licence key Input

Tags: windows, windows-installer, registry, license-key

I have made a windows Form application in c#. Now I want to make a windows installer package for the same application with license key input. Once license key has been entered and validated it should be saved in the windows registry.

Also I have unique requirement of using the license key only once. Once the software has been successfully installed automatically license key and the package should be expired so that in future if the client want to reinstall it he has to contact back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically a serial number validation is performed using a custom action included in the package. However, if the custom action just validates the number it cannot limit the serial number usage, i.e. the serial number can be shared by multiple users.

To have it with limited usage you can use a server-side validation, i.e. have the custom action connect to a web server, check the serial number against a DB from that server, and in that DB you can also check if that serial number was already activated or not.

In Advanced Installer user guide you can find a [server-side serial number validation sample](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-server-side-sn.html),
now sure what installer tool you are currently using.

NOTE, server side validation imposes that all your users will have an active internet connection during the installation process.

Comment: Thank you sir for your suggestion ..Will you please suggest me free installer tool.I am newbie in this field

Comment: Wix toolset (http://wixtoolset.org/) is free and powerful, but you will need to write the custom actions to do all the work, i.e. connect to the server, validate the keys, etc... Advanced Installer has a free edition too, but you need a commercial license to access the above mentioned feature.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would suggest punting the licensing requirements to application first run. It'll need to be there anyways in case the installer is somehow bypassed