# Wix installer accepting license key and saving in file

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix3

How can WIX installer accept license key in UI and save it in a specified location?

I have created a customized dialog to accept key from user and set it in the specified property but when  I  pass this input to custom action so as to save the value in a file, the custom action receives the initial value of the property not the one entered by user.

May be my install execute sequence is wrong. When should I schedule its execution?

```
  <InstallExecuteSequence> 
 <Custom Action="CA_SaveProperty" After="InstallFiles" /> 
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I have tried:

```
 After="InstallInitialize"
```

and

```
Before ="InstallFinalize"
```

What I want is the custom action to invoke after user enters the license key and before installer is ready to copy files.

Comment: This is a pretty common thing for an installer to do. Have you tried searching? Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244617/how-to-make-windows-installer-package-with-licence-key-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of struggle I found it was easy :

```
  <CustomAction Id="CA_SaveProperty"  BinaryKey="CA_SavePropertyDLL"  DllEntry="ReadProperty"  Execute="commit"  Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence> 
  <Custom Action="CA_SaveProperty" After="InstallFiles" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```